# Python 2.7, thread.Timer generates too many garbage threads not recycled

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I am running a python sample code on my windows, after each time executing the timer thread, a new thread created with  like below, but the old never recycled, it is really anoying the number of threads keep increasing, and I am afraid my software is going to consume the whole PC memory, just soon or later. I see many of others also met the same issue, when debugging with pydev, it will be reported "**TclError: out of stack space**" eventually!

Here is a list of my pydev debugging stack, it will increase and increase until "out of stack space", from the stack view, I see the number of thread is tremendous crazy...

```
Thread-1913 - pid_9200_id_155817632
Thread-1915 - pid_9200_id_156052840 
Thread-1917 - pid_9200_id_156052112 
Thread-1919 - pid_9200_id_156326208 
Thread-1921 - pid_9200_id_156326264
```

The error reported by pydev is like below:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 9200)
Exception in thread Thread-1921:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 1073, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:\work\tools\eclipseWorkspace\timerTest.py", line 46, in handle_function
    self.hFunction()
  File "D:\work\tools\eclipseWorkspace\timerTest.py", line 56, in printer
    lab['text'] = clock
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1337, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1330, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1321, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

Below is my code, it sets a timer and then invoke the function "loop" function

```
from threading import Timer, Thread, Event
from datetime import datetime
import Tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
lab = tk.Label(app, text="Timer will start in a sec")
lab.pack()

class perpetualTimer():

def __init__(self, t, hFunction):
    self.t = t
    self.hFunction = hFunction
    self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.loop)

def loop(self):
    self.hFunction()
    self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.loop)
    self.thread.start()

def start(self):
    self.thread.start()

def printer():
    tempo = datetime.today()
    clock = "{}:{}:{}".format(tempo.hour, tempo.minute, tempo.second)
    try:
        lab['text'] = clock
    except RuntimeError:
        exit()

t = perpetualTimer(0.1, printer)
t.start()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: if all you're doing is updating a clock, you definitely don't need to use threads. Are you wanting to solve the issue with threads, or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley, I just use this code to show my problem, I don't really need the 'clock' function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not execute on my Python. There is no need to cancel a Timer thread once it has fired. Just make a new one. Also, it is a lot cleaner to just put the first Timer creation in the initialization routine and wait for that to execute the handling function:

```
class perpetualTimer():
    def __init__(self, t, hFunction):
        self.t = t
        self.hFunction = hFunction
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)

    def handle_function(self):
        self.hFunction()
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)
        self.thread.start()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()
```

All the Timer threads terminate after they fire and will be garbage collected later. They will not fill all avalable memory.

Comment: Hi Johnathan, agree there is no need to add self.thread.cancel(), it was just for debugging purpose. But your code runs equally as mine that it generates a lot of garbage threads, I don't see any of them recycled, but they are increasing and increasing, looks never met the end...

Comment: I just made some changes based on your feedback. Also I changed the schedule time from 1 second to 0.1, then I can see the thread id increased to 1929
"Thread-1929 - pid_4060_id_147668888"